# What is the relationship between dependency constraints in "stack configuration", xxx.cabal, and cabal.config?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I haven't tried solving the issue yet; first I want to understand where the issue comes from:

```
TextTerra $ stack --nix test

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for TextTerra-0.1.0.0:
    easytest-0.2 from stack configuration does not match ==0.2.1  (latest matching version is 0.2.1)
needed since TextTerra is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' to ignore all version constraints and build anyway.

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing with many complicated constraint
    errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /home/brandon/workspace/TextTerra/stack.yaml:

- easytest-0.2.1

Plan construction failed.
```

There is now no other reference to easytest, particularly easytest-0.2; the single reference is what I just added:

```
TextTerra $ rg easytest
TextTerra.cabal
67:      , easytest == 0.2.1
```

However, there was a reference to easytest-0.2 in `cabal.config`. I'm not aware of the relevance of this file as a quick search doesn't turn up much and removing the file has no effect on the build (in particular, I get the same error message above).

Comment: Does this related to the curated/fixed-version packages in LTS?

Comment: "Does this related to the curated/fixed-version packages in LTS?" -- Likely so. Look for the `resolver` field in `stack.yaml`, then look for `easytest` in the Stackage page for the snapshot mentioned there (for instance, [this is the page for LTS 12.18](https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.18)).

Comment: Thanks, yeah updating the resolver fixed it! Perhaps that should be one of the approaches listed for solving the issue in the error message?

Comment: Possibly. I believe the error message makes the conservative assumption that you (or upstream) have already decided which resolver to use and just want to adjust your configuration for a new dependency (as opposed to, say, wanting to update the dependencies of an old project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In...

> `easytest-0.2` from stack configuration does not match `==0.2.1`

... the "stack configuration" means the set of packages specified through the `resolver` (typically a Stackage snapshot -- you can find lists of packages and versions in a snapshot at the [Stackage site](https://www.stackage.org/snapshots)) and the `extra-deps` in `stack.yaml`, while the `==0.2.1` constraint is what your `.cabal` file is asking. The suggestions given by the error message (ignoring `.cabal` upper bounds with `allow-newer`, and adding packages to `extra-deps`) are appropriate in the cases in which you want, or need, to build with a specific resolver. If that is not the case (say, if you are trying to update an old project to a recent LTS snapshot), you can also change the resolver to something that includes the packages and versions you are looking for (if such a resolver is available).